# Umbraco 7 slow on production server and keeps restarting

Tags: umbraco, iis-8, umbraco7

Local on my laptop the umbraco projects runs perfectly, but when I put it on the production server the backend is very slow.

**Specs of VPS:**

- Windows Server 2012
- 1 CPU with 2 Cores 2.2Ghz
- 4Gb RAM
- IIS8
- MSSQL Express

**Umbraco version**

7.4.1

Also when I add new nodes or other changes in the backend it sometimes hangs and then I see in the log that the application has restarted.

Log see below:

**Log rules**

```
2016-03-23 09:59:36,936 [P2616/D99/T30] INFO  Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Application shutdown. Details: ConfigurationChange

_shutDownMessage=IIS configuration change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.StopProcessing()
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
 2016-03-23 09:59:49,483 [P2616/D100/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Application shutdown. Details: ConfigurationChange

_shutDownMessage=IIS configuration change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.StopProcessing()
```

Anyone that has suggestions about this?

Comment: Probably need to install this patch: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6338
Also: always make sure to specify your umbraco version, might've be a bug that's already fixed.

Comment: @sebastiaan thanks for the intel I will test this. Version is 7.4.1.

Comment: This also sometimes happens when you have corrupt indexes. I think it's the`App_Data` folder you need to delete (umbraco will rebuild it), but back it up first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Windows Server 2012 R2 hotfix for this issue which can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480) - once installed the issue no longer occurs.

Comment: This one sorted it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and turned of examine indexing because it forced a configurationchange.

Try this out, go to /config/ExamineSettings.config

And comment out the providers

```
<providers>
  <!--
  <add name="InternalIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
       supportUnpublished="true"
       supportProtected="true"
       analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>

  <add name="InternalMemberIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoMemberIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
       supportUnpublished="true"
       supportProtected="true"
       analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>

    <add name="ExternalIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"/>
  -->
</providers>
```

It should stop the app pool restarting every time something is saved, but i don't know why the Indexer is forcing a refresh